# Show that $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$ if and only if $x\in A_k$ for all but finitely many of the sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Pf-Let $x\in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\implies x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k$ or $x\in\bigcap_{k=2}^{\infty}A_k$ and so on and so forth so that $x\in\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$, but there is a minimal $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in\bigcap_{k=n}^{m}A_k$ since its impossible for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ to satisfy $x\in\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k$. In other words, we obtain $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\subseteq\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\subseteq\bigcap_{k=n}^{m}A_k\implies x\in A_k$ for all but finitely many of the sets.

Conversely, Let $x\in A_k$ for all but finitely many sets $A_k\implies x\in\bigcap_{k=1}^{m}A_k$. Now, since $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\subseteq \bigcap_{k=1}^{m}A_k$ holds since adding sets to the intersection either keeps the same volume or decreases it. Now, removing $A_1$ preserves that $\bigcap_{k=2}^{\infty}A_k\subseteq \bigcap_{k=2}^{m}A_k$. So reduce this so that $A_{n-1}$ is removed and $\bigcap_{k=n}^{\infty}A_k\subseteq \bigcap_{k=n}^{m}A_k\implies x\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{k=n}^{m}A_k$

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Its proving the headline

Answer (score 2):

I found your argumentation muddled at best. You could reason much more clearly, e.g.:

So suppose $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$.

This means, by the definition of union, that for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that $x \in \bigcap_{k=n_0}^\infty A_k$.

So for *all* $k \ge n_0$, we know that $x \in A_k$, so $x$ is in all $A_k$, except possibly not in $A_0, A_1, \ldots, A_{n_0-1}$, so $x$ is in all but finitely many $A_k$.

The reverse is quite simple: suppose $x$ is in all but finitely many $A_k$, and suppose that the $A_{n_1}, A_{n_2}, \ldots, A_{n_m}$ are all finitely many $A_k$ such that $x \notin A_k$. So let $n_0:=\max(n_1,n_2,\ldots, n_m)+1$ which is a well-defined integer and we know that if $k \ge n_0$, this $A_k$ is not one of the sets that $x$ is *not* in, so $x \in A_k$ for all those $k$.

It follows that $x \in \bigcap_{k=n_0}^\infty A_k$ and so $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty A_k$ as required.

Comment: Nice answer (+1), minor typo on third line ($n_x$ should be $n_0$).

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thx. I fixed the typo.